# Is MKMapView used in Apple Map?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I used a `MKMapView` in my app to show current user location. After I am done with the app, I want to check whether my map is show the right location, I compared the map in my app and Apple Maps App. And I realized that they're different.

The question is Does Apple Maps use `MKMapView` class? If not what can I do to make a map like that.
I have a problem with my app that I can't use google map.

Comment: Which version of ios are u working on ?

Comment: Compare your app with Apple App ?

Comment: compare the mapview in my app with apple map. Showing same location on 2 ipad. one with apple map and one with mkmapview in my app

Comment: I am working on ios6 and 7

Comment: Can you be more clear about difference, like post a screenshot?

Comment: sorry. Sad that I don't have enough reputation to do that

Comment: And can upload the picture to some other service and post a link here

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/vtpvh577ritra73y89gs

On the left is MKMapView in my app and the right is Apple Map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Apple Maps.app uses `MKMapView`. However `MKMapView` has options to change its visualisation mode. It has 3 options:

```
[<mapView> setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[<mapView> setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
[<mapView> setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
```

I am not sure about what is the difference in your app map and Apple Maps map, but this could be it.

Good luck.

Comment: No. I used the same type: MKMapTypeHybrid. But in apple map it's shiny, beautiful, clear. On mkmapview in my app it's opaque

Comment: @user2434837 Oh well, if that is the problem, you should consult with a designer.